# how to join 2 select?

Tags: php, sql, join, select, where-clause

I should enter another query to get the data from another table, how to do it?

first query

```
$actor_id = $_GET["id"];
$nome= $row ['nome'];
$sql = "select * from gallery WHERE actor_id_fk=". $actor_id;
$rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

to be included in the code

```
$sql = "select * from actor WHERE actor_id=". $actor_id;
```

Comment: Hi, start by looking up the JOIN syntax in your favourite SQL manual or tutorial site

Comment: You also should look at parameterizing your query. This is open to SQL injections. To join to unrelated `selects` a `union` would be used, they require the same number of columns being selected. Since these tables are relate a `join` should be used.

Answer (score 1):

That's a simple join:

```
select *              -- better enumerate the columns here that use "*"
from actor a
inner join gallery g on g.actor_id_fk = a.actor_id
where a.actor_id = ?  -- and better use prepared statements!
```

Comment: `WHERE actor_id_fk=". $actor_id`   `WHERE actor_id=". $actor_id` how to do?
sorry I'm not a programmer

Comment: @Alex: the `on` clause of the `join`  matches rows between the two tables. You just need to replace the `?` with your `$actor_id` parameter.

Comment: ok, try, Thank you

Comment: I should get this field from the actor table
to pass it into the variable `$nome= $row ['nome'];`

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work

Comment: here is the code  https://yadi.sk/d/ncpgUrxUytgNmg

Comment: it doesn't work because it can't find the path, which is in the variable `$nome`                                 `$createDeletePath = "../image_upload/actor/uploads/$nome ($actor_id)/".$getIamgeName;`